# How do you fade out an object in a scene from an animation clip?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I have a scene in Unity, with animated assets. The animated asset is a custom prefab effect with multiple animated objects nested within it. The asset runs in a loop, all the objects are assigned a PBR shader using shadergraph. Some of the assets fade out at the end, while others simply disappear. I can control when an object disappears on the timeline by disabling it. But others need to fade away. I suspect I can fade out those objects by changing the alpha of the PBR shadergraph material at a specific point in time in the animation clip. Can anyone advise the process or links to tutorials on how to fade out an object, starting at a specific point in time in an animation clip, and also set the duration required when the object becomes completely invisible ?

Comment: The available animation properties of the object do not have an “alpha” property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you wanted you would need to add an [`AnimationEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html) into your Animaton.

You can do that with the [Rectangle Symbol](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-AnimationWindowEvent.html) you find over the Animation Window Properties.

You can now use that [`AnimationEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationEvent.html) to call a Function in a Script that will fade out the object.

Also make sure to pass in what amount of time you want to fade the object as a `float` and the current `GameObject` as an `Object` into the function.

**AnimationEvent Function:**

```cs
public void FadeOutEvent(float waitTime, object go) {
    // Get the GameObject fromt the recieved Object.
    GameObject parent = go as GameObject;

    // Get all ChildGameObjects and try to get their PBR Shader
    List<RPBShader> shaders = parent
        .GetComponentsInChildren(typeof(RPBShader)).ToList();

    // Call our FadeOut Coroutine for each Component found.
    foreach (var shader in shaders) {
        // If the shader is null skip that element of the List.
        if (shader == null) {
            continue;
        }
        StartCoroutine(FadeOut(waitTime, shader));
    }
}
```

`RPBShader` would the Type of the Component you want to get.

---

To fade out the Object over time we would need to use an `IEnumerator`.

**Fade Out Coroutine:**

```cs
private IEnumerator FadeOut(float waitTime, RPBShader shader) {
    // Decrease 1 at a time, 
    // with a delay equal to the time, 
    // until the Animation finished / 100.
    float delay = waitTime / 100;
  
    while (shader.alpha > 0) {
        shader.alpha--;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    }
}
```

`shader.alpha` would be the current's Object PBR Shader Alpha Value that you want to decrease.

---

Comment: So, controlling the alpha of a PBR material can only be done via code ?

Comment: If it is assigned at runtime (that's how i understood it from your question) then yes as far as i know you can only edit at runtime via code.